# select using XPath with considering namespace and prefix

Tags: java, xpath

How to select an XML using XPath without considering namespace and prefix

tried

```
/*:OrderPerson/OrderUser/
```

But returns error

```
org.jdom.JDOMException: Invalid XPath expression: .... 
Unexpected ':'
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2607432/183791

Comment: [`/*[local-name() = 'OrderPerson']`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/123005/358679)

Comment: Wildcards for the namespace is an XPath 2.0 feature. If you want to match on the `local-name()` and ignore the namespace, use @dash1e answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this expression

```
/*[local-name()='OrderPerson']/OrderUser/
```

Answer (score -1):

Your xpath query has not a valid syntax 
try with 
/OrderPerson/OrderUser/*