# XPath to parse JAX-RS result

Tags: java, jax-rs, foursquare

I don't know how to use XPath so I can parse the result of the XML I got from JAX-RS and put it into an ArrayList or something, here's the code I have so far, it generates a String... but I want to be able to use XPath to parse it, as it's better to parse XML rather than parsing String.

```
private Client client = Client.create();
    private List<String> venueName = new ArrayList<String>();

    private String getNearbyVenues(double lattitude, double longitude){
        WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://api.foursquare.com/v1/venues");
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
        queryParams.add("geolat", String.valueOf(lattitude));
        queryParams.add("geolong", String.valueOf(longitude));
        return webResource.queryParams(queryParams).get(String.class);
    }
```

The result goes something like [this](http://api.foursquare.com/v1/venues?geolat=51.543724&geolong=-0.102365)

Comment: what are you looking to find using XPATH. XPath is generally used to search for things in XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an answer of mine to another question that explains how to use the Java SE javax.xml.xpath libraries:

- [How to use XPath on xml docs having default namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939636/how-to-use-xpath-on-xml-docs-having-default-namespace/3941277#3941277)