# JAXP XPathFactory Namespaces

Tags: java, android, xml, xpath

I am trying to retrieve one node from a xml doc in android(java).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config:Manifest xmlns:config="http://leaflabs.com/manifest.config.xsd"> 
  <config:Text config:name="siteowner" config:desc="Site owner" config:transform="title"/>
  <config:Text config:name="siteowner1" config:desc="Site owner" config:transform="title"/>
</config:Manifest>
```

XPATH

```
config:Manifest/config:Text[@config:name='siteowner']
```

I am using JAXP XPathFactory. The problem i am getting is get null back everytime.

I made sure my xpath was correct  made sure my document builder NamespaceAware is set to true and i even followed a [Example](http://www.edankert.com/defaultnamespaces.html)
(at the bottom of page) that implement the NamespaceContext but i still get nothing.

I looked at a stackoverflow Post but nobody answered the guy 
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288892/jaxp-processing-xml-with-namespace)

What am i doing wrong

Comment: Your **relative** XPath expression is fine as long as context node is document root. You could use also this absolute expression: `/config:Manifest/config:Text[@config:name='siteowner']`. If this result in a empty node set, do check if your namespace URI binding is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue in your code is the factory is not namespace aware. There is another thread that resolves this problem, [How to use XPath on xml docs having default namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939636/how-to-use-xpath-on-xml-docs-having-default-namespace)

Suggest you try something like this,

> XPath xPath =
>   XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
>   xPath.setNamespaceContext(new
>   MyNamespaceContext());

Answer (score 0):

Not a 100% sure but I believe you need a token in front of you xpath statement:

I would try the following:

$this/config:Manifest/config:Text[@config:name='siteowner']

And if that doesn't work try this:

/config:Manifest/config:Text[@config:name='siteowner']

And if neither of those work try this:

//config:Manifest/config:Text[@config:name='siteowner']