# how to retrieve XML data using XPath which contains namespace in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

i know there are plenty of this topic in this page but sadly, i still cant get my solution..

here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:Request xmlns:ns1="http://www.sea.com">
<ns1:PayrollRequest>
  <ns1:PayrollCost>
    <ns1:PayrollID>123</ns1:PayrollID>
    <ns1:BatchID>7770</ns1:BatchID>
    <ns1:CompanyId>001</ns1:CompanyId>
    <ns1:GrossPay>60000</ns1:GrossPay>
  </ns1:PayrollCost>
</ns1:PayrollRequest>
</ns1:Request>
```

and this is my code in java:

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XPathTry {

public static void main(String[] args) 
throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, 
IOException, XPathExpressionException {

DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = 
DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse("SamplePayroll2.xml");
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();


// display all
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//PayrollCost/*/text()");


Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
   }
  }
}
```

ya, as usual, i cant get the output as it only displays:

```
Process exited with exit code 0.
```

the output will only display when i remove the ns:1 which the code for the xml will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request xmlns:ns1="http://www.sea.com">
<PayrollRequest>
    <PayrollCost>
        <PayrollID>123</PayrollID>
        <BatchID>7770</BatchID>
        <CompanyId>001</CompanyId>
        <GrossPay>60000</GrossPay>
    </PayrollCost>
</PayrollRequest>
</Request>
```

The problem is, all the suggestions i found in the net none seems to be working:

for example, i already tried the

```
/*/namespace::*[name()='']

//*[local-name() = 'Element' and namespace-uri() = namespace-uri(/*)]

/*[local-name()=' ']/*[local-name()=' ']/*[local-name()=' ']
```

etc2..

the only best output i can get is, it will display:

```
null
```

can anyone give me the correct code for my problem?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939636/how-to-use-xpath-on-xml-docs-having-default-namespace/3941277#3941277

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to have to create a subclass of [javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext.html) and set it on `xpath`:

```
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public Iterator getPrefixes(final String namespaceURI) {
        return Collections.singleton("ns1").iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPrefix(final String namespaceURI) {
        return "ns1";
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI(final String prefix) {
        return "http://www.sea.com";
    }
});
```

Then you can add the namespace prefix to the XPath expression:

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//ns1:PayrollCost/*/text()");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a NamespaceContext for your XPath expression.  You can read more about how to do this [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-using-xpath-with-namespaces-and.html)