# Get XML value from xpath with namespace

Tags: java, xml, xpath

To be clear, my xml and its XPath are dynamic, anything may come, so no hard coded values to parse XML value from XPath. Here is my XML and XPath constructed.

```
String xml = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:com=\"http://com\" xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><com:addition><com:a>1</com:a><com:b>1</com:b></com:addition></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
Document doc = UtilityFunction.createXMLDocument(xml);
System.out.println("Value "+XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile("//soapenv:Envelope[1]/soapenv:Body[1]/com:addition[1]/com:a[1]").evaluate(doc).toString());
```

Empty is getting printed. How can I use namespace to get XML value from xpath. How to enable namespace in compilation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to retrieve XML data using XPath which contains namespace in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221652/how-to-retrieve-xml-data-using-xpath-which-contains-namespace-in-java)

Comment: to which library XPathFactory belongs? is it JDOM2?

Comment: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory factory

Answer (score 0):

`XPathFactory.newXPath()` returns an [XPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html) object.

Create a [NamespaceContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext.html) object, set it up to know about your namespace bindings, and call `.setNamespaceContext()` on the `XPath` object.

Then compile the `XPath` and invoke as usual.

(I presume this duplicates answers given in some of the "Related" questions at right, so I'm not going to give a code sample. It's simple enough.)